# reusing a webpart in another solution in sharepoint 2010 results a "500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a webpart that was used in an old visual studio solution as a stand alone project.

I copied this webpart project to a new visual studio solution, deployed the webpart to the new web application port and used it on a page.

after I insert the webpart If I try to edit the page through the web interface Ribbon-> Edit I get the error message: "500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR".

I tried "CustomErrors="OFF" in web.config, Checked windows error logs, but couldn't get any more details about the error.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change CallStack="False" to CallStack="true" (search for it) and set debug="true"

Then update the question with the error (if you still need help)